# Execution of custom code after successful logged in (SharePoint 2013 with Windows authentication)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, windows-authentication

Is there any way to execute custom code after user logged in successfully
(Windows-based authentication)?

Comment: whats the context of this question. please provide some background and problem you are facing.

Comment: Probably you could hack something by using a custom claims provider. What are you trying to do?

Comment: lol, i want to restrict sharepoint site access for some users from outside of environments so need to check if specific user not in local environment then need to redirect access denied page

Comment: what's wrong with question and why got negative points???????

Comment: in short, if i putting my code in master page then it calls every time so i m not putting code in masterpage i want to execute code once after login. getting my point??

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be to develop an HTTP module (a class implementing `IHttpModule`), declare it in web.config (could be with a [`WebConfigModifications`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb861909(v=office.14).aspx) used from inside a feature event receiver scoped WebApp). By subscribing to its `AuthenticateRequest` event you can run code after any request is done with autthentication.